# Handle Question changing Topic/Problem

Tags: discussion, edits

Today I asked this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817663/div-only-showing-up-when-debugging).

After getting rid of my first error (handling ajax calls synchronously) the topic is shifting onto another topic/problem (the handling of the response).
Therefore the part of the question is outdated and the title does not describe the problem well.

Should I refactor my Question/Title or create a new Question?

Comment: Create a new question. Providing moving targets, isn't nice for the users that already gave you an answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - This is really a duplicate, I search with the wrong words

Comment: No worries.  Your question is one I remember answering, which is how I found the duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never edit your question when it would invalidate the answer(s) on it.  This is a Q & A site not a forum.  If you ask a question and it gets answered and then that answer leads you to another issue that you can't figure out then you should post another question about the new issue.  Adding it to the original question makes it look like the answer only answered half the question when it actually answered/fixed your original problem.

You can link back to the original question so people can see what you had and how you fixed it as someone else might give you an approach that avoids causing the new issue first place.