# Should we rollback to the version which has "format issue" because it has already been answered?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I'm talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34825139/5299236). So, the string is:

```
> SEND OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
> Access-Control-Allow- l-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,
> Phant-Private-Key Content-Type: text/plain X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 300
> X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 297
> X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 1452931335.777
> Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2016 07:50:17 GMT 
> Set-Cookie: SERVERID=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-197 0 00:00:01 GMT; path=/ Cache-control: private
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But actually, those `>` do not really exist, they are just the result of a format error.

As [I asked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825139/extract-timestamp-from-large-string/34825324?noredirect=1#comment57392484_34825139):

> Are these `>` really exist or just a format issue?

And [OP answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825139/extract-timestamp-from-large-string/34825324?noredirect=1#comment57392512_34825139):

> @Kevin It was a format issue. Thanks I have corrected

Then OP edited their question and removed those `>`.

---

But the problem is, the existing answers are all about the *first version*. So an answerer rollbacked the edit, [and said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825139/extract-timestamp-from-large-string/34825324?noredirect=1#comment57392703_34825139):

> I've rolled back your question to its original form, before you made two substantive changes that invalidated existing answers. If you like, feel free to accept an answer that answers *this question* as it stands. If you have a *substantively different question*, create a new question for it.

I know that if OP "edited their question to *ask another question*", then we should rollback. But what about this case?

So, actually, OP *doesn't need the answers*. Also *I think* this isn't OP's fault, just because they're new here and don't know how to format code correctly.

Is this rollback correct?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for as far as I see the only answer that would be invalid is TigerT3's answer. And he [did fix it for the new format](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34825240/revisions) but rolled it back along with the question.

Comment: @Thaillie: Oh yeah, right. I think he wants rollback the question to the *original version*. But I don't know that this is also *edited the question to ask another question* or otherwise.

Comment: Ugh, what happens in [regex] should stay in [regex].

Comment: @Thaillie - Did you look at the other answers? Salman's answer was just as invalidated as mine, and made the exact same edit. Do you want to give the impression that I'm some nefarious editor helping no one but myself? Come on.

Comment: I don't think the dupes are fit in this case (I didn't say that I dissagree with them and I don't want vote to reopen). For example, NathanOliver said that *You should never edit your question when it would invalidate the answer(s) on it.* In this case, others edited their answers immediately (since they just need change the `>` to `\n`) and let them become validated again. And the problem is, after rollback, they'll all be invalidated (again). So instead of rollback all the things, I think just move on is better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We should not cater for answerers who do not try to understand the actual problem, but instead roll up their sleeves and apply their only known problem-solving hammer to each problem they see (in this case: regular expressions).

Because that would mean we cannot edit any question where any answer has been posted that refers to any content from the question, even if that content was posted wrongly (copy-paste error, formatting error, ...).

If the question as posted is unclear, or able for multiple interpretations, it's the answerer's loss for answering it. You **should not answer unclear questions**, but ask for clarification in comments instead.

Also, the change that OP did (remove the preceding `>` from each line) does not significantly change the question, nor the answers, so it should not have been rolled back.

Comment: I'm confused by your first paragraph.  How are regular expression related to *this* question?

Comment: @Alan I just mean that there are a lot of users eager to answer _any_ question in order to gain some reputation, without wanting to understand the problem domain.

Comment: I _did_ try to understand the actual problem, the question was _tagged_ with regex, I even included a non-regex solution that would work for some cases, and I did at first edit my question to take into account the formatting mistake. I only came to my rollback decision after the second piece of new information, that would've meant complete rewrites for two existing answers. I don't like the broad brush you're painting me with.

Comment: @Tigerhawk it's _your_ problem that you see a regex tag and go _"I know, I'll write a regex for this poor person"_. The actual problem is parsing HTTP headers, and anyone with any experience in that field knows what an HTTP message looks like and that non-conforming servers will omit required headers like `Date`. Also, when purely looking at the regex part of things, you should know that any text parsing question must explicitly state the required number of occurrences, in this case `0-1`. If that's unclear, you vote to close as such and post a comments asking for clarification - don't answer.

Comment: Once again, I tried not to write a regex. The first part of my answer is a non-regex solution that would work for some cases. You can look at my other answers to regex questions and you will see that _they often contain no regex_, starting with something like "you don't need regex for that." I don't know about HTTP headers, so all I could do was take the question at face value and do my best on what I originally thought was a clear question. I don't appreciate this inaccurate condemnation.

Comment: @Tigerhawk and I don't like people who roll back helpful clarifications because they answered an unclear question.

Comment: As I've been saying, 1. I (and a few other answerers) didn't think the original question was unclear, 2. the clarifications turned it into a completely different question, and 3. there is vast precedent for rolling back chameleon questions that do this.

Comment: I'm also not fond of the way you're attacking people instead of ideas or actions.

Comment: @Tigerhawk you're misunderstanding what "chameleon questions" are. Adding relevant details is not turning a question into a different question altogether. When you answer a text parsing question, all details about that text and its patterns must be clear. If you have any experience in that subject, you **know** that strings can be optional, required and/or repeated. If that is not mentioned at all in the question, you cannot assume anything, so you _need_ to ask for clarification before answering. I'm also not targeting anyone specifically; I'm explaining my opinion about certain actions.

Comment: "Thanks for the answers to my question, but wait, it also has to handle X" that 100% negates existing answers is a chameleon question and I will continue to roll back such questions with a comment explaining that a new question should be asked in a new question.

Comment: @Tigerhawk you're acting like the question _"I want to get content X from string Y"_, amended with _"Oh, but X doesn't *have* to be present"_ is a change that fundamentally changes questions and answers. My stance is that an answerer with any experience in the field should **know** that in such situations, that's an outcome that is to be expected, and that that should be clarified **before** answering. Sec the question _"I want to get string X from string Y"_ is not unclear, but inherently it has so many problems that you should know not to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I am the answerer who rolled back the question (and my answer, and another poster's answer).

The original question was specific and answerable, and it got two answers (one of which was mine). The OP then commented on their question, saying that part of the sample input was an error due to formatting. That accounts for the edit to both answers. Then the OP commented on both answers, asking "but what if the original input is (unexpected condition XYZ)?". Since A) accounting for that would make both existing answers not just a little bit wrong but 100% wrong and B) I then saw a few more potential issues that would have required more clarification and edits (the OP never answered my comments asking for clarification on those issues), I recognized what is commonly referred to as a chameleon question.

There is some precedent on those, which I researched (Google search used: `site:meta.stackoverflow.com question edit invalidate answer`) before taking action:

1. [Dealing with questions that are edited after my answer has been accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted)
2. [Should a question edit be rolled back if it appears to be a follow-up to an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299405/should-a-question-edit-be-rolled-back-if-it-appears-to-be-a-follow-up-to-an-answ)
3. [how to deal with OP asking another questions after answering original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275138/how-to-deal-with-op-asking-another-questions-after-answering-original-question)
4. [Link for poor or ever-growing questions to better explain why people stop answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer)
5. [Handle Question changing Topic/Problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306958/handle-question-changing-topic-problem)
6. [Dealing with solutions that end with a new error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300966/dealing-with-solutions-that-end-with-a-new-error)
7. [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)
8. [How much change to the question is too much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much)

Since it seemed unanimous that chameleon questions should be rolled back so that the original, unique question with its helpful answers can be helpful to the next person who finds them (and I've [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991885/how-to-split-a-delimiter-string-and-store-it-as-array-in-python) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805446/how-to-group-object-of-the-class-by-attribute-and-plot-data-using-matplotlib) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991885/how-to-split-a-delimiter-string-and-store-it-as-array-in-python) [anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352689/not-all-arguments-converted-error-in-python-string-format) (Google search used: `site:stackoverflow.com "tigerhawkt3" substantive "new question"`) - yes, I did the research again just to make sure), I went ahead with the rollbacks.

Anyone who knows a bit about my attitude toward regular expressions will know that a lot of my answers on regex questions start with "you don't need a regex for that." Indeed, my answer on *the very question we're discussing* has a non-regex solution that works in certain cases (the OP answered my clarifying question on that after I answered the question, so I just left that part in there in case a future reader has an applicable case). It's far from my "only known problem-solving hammer," and I must say, I'm a bit bothered that the accepted answer on this Meta question makes that assumption with zero research.

TL;DR: I've done it correctly before, I did it correctly this time, and, by Skeet, I'll do it correctly again.

Comment: And this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much