# Down voting because of tagging mistake

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation

I'm talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195290/find-all-elements-of-arraylist/35198690) question.

Someone removed its original tag [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and added other tag ([vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net)). I replied according to VB.NET. Later, someone else changed the tag back how it was originally.

My answer was downvoted (may be him or someone else).

It doesn't make much sense because of couple of reputation point, but does it also affect reputation of the reviewer/moderator (because his/her mistake)?

Comment: _"but does it also affects reputation of the reviewer/moderator (because he made mistake)?"_ No.

Comment: You could always delete your answer if you think it's not useful. You'll get back the rep from the downvotes if you do.

Comment: What does `Probably your answer is given here and more description is given on this link.` mean? I think there's probably more reasons to down vote that "answer" than language used.

Comment: FWIW I don't think posting a C# answer to a 'how do I do this in VB.NET' question is helpful anyway. It may be easy to convert between the two if you know how, but if they were asking in the first place they likely wouldn't know how.

Comment: There's also a deleted answer with the VB.NET LINQ syntanx, and there's a comment on it that says ArrayList does not have the same methods as Array and List, so LINQ wouldn't work or compile anyway. So whoever that was might have voted yours down too because they thought you were wrong.

Comment: Regarding "language used" in that post, not all developer are English people and knows proper English sentence formation like English man. and all people can not form English sentence like given in Shakespeare's book. This is programming related website so focus should be on solution not how sentence formed or what type of sentence used except abusive or aggressive must not be allowed. otherwise people will focus on programming solution or English language?

Comment: Regarding "C# used", I have ready reply from reputed persons on StackoverFlow that the StackOverflow is not for beginner to learn. and any .Net developer including beginner know that there are coverter available from C# to VB and VB to C# and they works well. and a normal developer can easily guess basic syntax from one language to other even java to c# or VB.

Comment: See many of users have started down voting my reply on that post because of just asking information regarding it.

Comment: @par calm down. Tzhx never said HE downvoted you for language. You wanted to know why you got downvoted. It is possible it is because of language (do i agree with it? No, for the reasons you mention. Can it still be why you got downvoted? Absolutely.) dont come to meta asking for reasons if you dont want to listen....

Answer (score 17):

A few points on your answer:

- It's basically a guess-answer. *"Try this"*, no explanation given. Add explanation to the code you post.
- It's copy-pasted from another answer to another question. If you believe a question to be answered in another question, flag as duplicate instead of copy-pasting an answer.
- You're responding with C# to a Visual Basic question. Attempt to answer the question in the language asked.

All this warrants downvotes.

Then comes the tagging issue. My stance is: when a question is ambiguous (tagged with language X but showing code containing elements of language Y), one should not answer, but close to vote as unclear and ask the OP to check their tags again. If you do answer an ambiguous question by guessing, you willingly risk being downvoted.

See also:

- [Should we rollback to the version which has "format issue" because it has already been answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314847/should-we-rollback-to-the-version-which-has-format-issue-because-it-has-alread)
- [How much change to the question is too much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much)
- Note that mere mistagging does *not* make a question a [Chameleon Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: Given reference of any other website or stackoverlfow link doesn't mean that its duplicate post. sometime intension of giving reference of other link is to give direction and original poster should provide his effort to get the answer.

Comment: I think you are not getting the point. Giving reference doesn't mean its duplicate post. and benefit of giving reference of link is a person can see more detail or more information on that post which is not possible to copy paste in reply. So do you mean giving reference of related(no totally duplicate) question is laziness? In that case StackOverflow should add one point in help that "a person should not post link in reply (answer or comment) , instead he should copy its content in the reply".

Comment: No, you are missing the point. You literally copied the code from another answer and linked to it, without providing additional information. That is not "giving reference", that is plagiarism.

Comment: I understand that copied code but I didn't want to get copy so I posted with its link. so my intension was to give solution and it was quite obvious and didn't require more information. Didn't think that it still require posting unnecessary text to describe it. and I think any beginner develop also can not think that it will require more information looking at it. and I also strongly believe or expect that reply on StackOverflow may or may not be like any paid support like Telerik or DevExpress support ticket system.

Comment: That's fine, but we have a different opinion on that. I don't believe in "unnecessary text" accompanying code. I don't believe in "code that speaks for itself". I want an answer to explain what the code posted in that answer does.

Comment: You believe or not but there may be self explanatory code many time. mainly small and easy code.

Comment: No, I don't believe in that. For why, see my answer in [What should a minimal answer contain?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain/298811#298811).

Comment: Apart from that, we simply cannot ignore the fact that you **copied the code off another answer without adding anything to it**. That should be enough of a hint that the question is a duplicate. Do note that Stack Overflow is not a forum, and that we're not here to help everyone get their program to work; we're here to build a knowledge base. By copying content you're spreading out knowledge, which is bad for maintainability and findability.

Comment: in that case I believe you are forcing your thought on other. I think for that small reply allows replier to use save time and use that time on other question.

Comment: No, that is not just my opinion. We're trying to build a collection of high-quality questions and answers, and a code dump can never be of high quality.

Comment: agree, but on asking question people will get correct or incorrect, description or short, self explanatory or some time no answer. and I have seen many time wrong answer marked as Answer and no one reviewed that.

Comment: Are you just going to keep talking in circles until I say you're correct? You've done something you shouldn't have, and I and others have pointed out what you did wrong. Accept that, learn from it and change your behavior.

Comment: I am also asking you same "Are you just going to keep talking in circles until I say you're correct"? Truly say I believe that many people who got authority (by reputation) are using in wrong way. There would be many meaning of "Wrong way". People with too good reputation believe they are extra ordinary and they are always correct. and people with low reputation like me can do anything because of too much restriction. and its barrier for building KNOWLEDGE BASE. Ok I am leaving this discussion now.

Comment: @par if the answer from the link is "self explanatory" and you just need to point to it,dupe it, period. That's how the site was designed. This isnt "opinions", but the inherent design of how stack was built.  Oh and even there... You keep saying"it's your opinion". While true, people vote based on their opinions,right or wrong. Learn to listen to these opinions a bit more....